# "notes on" vs. "notes to"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

We usually say "Notes to financial statements" rather than "Notes on ..." However, for other uses, we often say "notes on (something)."

I think "notes on" means "notes explaining about something" and "notes to" means "notes written for someone or something."

Examples:

- notes on the subject matter
- notes to self

By extension, I assume we would say "Notes on financial statements," but we customary say "Notes to financial statements."

Could anyone explain why this is the case? Thank you!

Comment: Please could you include the full text where 'notes to' is used? It's currently a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Perhaps it is the usage jargon of accountants. For example an invoice – **To: preparing accounts, £1000.00**